# Как записать данные типа float в .txt файл построчно?

Tags: python

Есть 3 переменные - `minValue`, `maxValue`, `avgValue`.

Их надо записать в `.txt` файл, чтобы каждое значение переменной было на одной строке.

```
result = open('result.txt', 'w') 
result.write(???)
```

Заранее, огромно благодарен! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ, поступивший от @Sergey Gornostaev вполне Вас должен устроить, однако замечу, что

1) Следует закрывать файл после того, как Вы его используете:

```
result = open('file.txt', 'w')
result.write(str(minValue) + '\n')
result.write(str(maxValue) + '\n')
result.write(str(argValue) + '\n')
result.close()
```

2) А также советую автору использовать контекстный менеджер *with*:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    result.write(str(minValue) + '\n')
    result.write(str(maxValue) + '\n')
    result.write(str(argValue) + '\n')
```

Этот метод более читабельный и нет необходимости закрывать файл.

UPD:
Как было замечено @jfs, можно использовать такие конструкции, как

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    print(min_value, max_value, arg_value, sep='\n', file=file)
```

Или:

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    with redirect_stdout(file):
        print(minValue)
        print(maxValue)
        print(argValue)
```

Comment: `print(min_value, max_value, arg_value, sep='\n', file=file)`

Comment: если несколько  print() вызовов удобней, то можно contextlib.redirect_stdout() использовать, чтобы не указывать file параметр постоянно.

Answer (score 1):

```
result.write(str(minValue) + '\n')
result.write(str(maxValue) + '\n')
result.write(str(argValue) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(minValue, file=result)
print(maxValue, file=result)
print(argValue, file=result)
```

Comment: на сколько я знаю, это плохой тон :)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант от @Mr Morgan вполне рабочий, но дублирования кода лучше избегать:

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for value in [minValue, maxValue, avgValue]:
        out_file.write(str(value) + '\n')
```

Comment: Нефакт, например вариант Morgan длинее на 1 строку, но более легковесен. тк в вашем варианте создается лишний `[]` а так же происходит итерация по нему.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант от @lecron вполне рабочий, но в таком случае можно и не использовать конструкцию `for`, используя *List comprehensions* и конкатенацию строк:

```
with open('foobar.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in [minValue, maxValue, avgValue]))
```

Comment: Визуально грязнее. Не всегда экономия строк ведет к лучшей читаемости.

Comment: @Lecron, не совсем понимаю, что тут визуально грязнее

Comment: На вкус и цвет... мне, если смотрю на простыню чужого кода, или своего старого, забытого, проще увидеть логику при явном цикле. Вне контекста кода и в контексте заданного вопроса, на трехстрочных примерах, разницы может и нет. List comprehensions считаю выгодным при явном формировании нового списка, как замену list.append(). Если логику можно построить без append и списочного выражения, явный цикл имхо предпочтительнее.

Comment: @Lecron, ну а мне изначально не совсем понятно, для чего вы использовали цикл при 3х переменных, генерируя все тот же новых список. ИМХО тут стоит сделать так, как предложили в принятом ответе, дублирование кода не всегда плохо, например, в таком маленьком примере. Был бы у нас действительно огромный набор элементов - стоило бы изначально их засунуть в список и уже по нему бежать в цикле.

Comment: Копипаста — потенциальный источник ошибок и препятствие для редактирования. Например в примере Mr Morgan произошло рассогласование имени переменной блока with и записи в файл. Где лучше исправлять или случайно пропустить ошибку, при тройном повторе или где действие фактически выделено в инлайн-функцию с аргументами? Поэтому в этом примере, может разницы и нет, однако лучше привыкать к более четкой организации.

Comment: @Lecron, я и написал: "например, в таком маленьком примере". А рассогласование произошло просто потому что человек скопипастил код из чужого ответа и  добавил свою строку - это уже проблема не дублирования кода, а невнимательности.

Comment: Вообще-то, обсуждение начато по сравнению нашего кода, когда оба используют цикл. И это логично, в комментариях к вашему примеру. Зачем вы его перевели на другие рельсы, непонятно. Впрочем, каждый высказал свое мнение и это нормально.

Comment: @Lecron, "Например в примере Mr Morgan", вы перевели рельсы, не я. На сем не вижу смысла продолжать, это уже не обсуждение, а какой-то цирк.